# OCaml online: List.sort compare is not working

Tags: list, sorting, module, ocaml

I am testing the following OCaml's online environment: https://try.ocamlpro.com/

However, my algorithms are failing because of the use of `List.sort compare x`, where `x` is a list of integers. I have tested the following basic code `List.sort compare [2; 3; 1];;` and seen it throws an error:

```
Error: This expression has type ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> int
but an expression was expected of type
  ('a -> 'a -> int) -> ('a -> 'a -> int) -> int
Type 'a list is not compatible with type 'a -> 'a -> int
```

The online environment specifies it is OCaml 4.13.1, so does this mean `compare` is deprecated? In that case, how can I substitute it?

---

EDIT:

I have seen the following:

If you just write `List.sort compare [2; 3; 1];;` in the online environment, then it returns the correct output `- : int list = [1; 2; 3]`.

However, if you load the `List module` with `open List`, then the error above is thrown.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There's not enough information here to conclusively determine the cause.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the basic example you say you have tried. I still cannot reproduce it myself though.

Comment: No problem! I have edited it to make it clearer :))

Comment: Ah, in that case it's just because `List` has a `compare` function that will shadow the polymorphic one from `Pervasives`. And that's why you should be careful to use `open`.

Comment: Thanks! And what can I do in case I would like to open ```List``` in order to use other functions from it? For instance, if I do not load ```List```, then I cannot use ```tl``` to get the tail of a list.

Comment: I think I can do this last one by specifying ```List.tl```. But I would prefer to load ```List```, since I use ```tl``` much more times. So is there any way to load ```List``` and then specify ```compare``` is not from ```List```? Kind of a ```noList.compare``` or a ```primitive.compare```, to say.

Comment: You can use `Stdlib.compare` (or `Pervasives.compare` in older versions) to reference the original one. There are also ways you could "import" single functions, but it's not very straight-forward or idiomatic. The idiomatic approach is to not open modules that weren't specifically designed to be opened.

Comment: Thank you very much! For this concrete case, it also suited for me to use ```Int.compare```.

Comment: Another important point is that using `List.tl` is almost always an error. In nearly all cases, using pattern matching is a superior alternative.

Comment: Many people don’t like opening modules, because it brings in context names which do not really make sense alone—and might shadow other names, as you discovered. If you find that typing full module names is too boring, then, rather than opening them, you can locally alias them to shorter names, e.g. `module L = List`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, by opening the List module, you've now shadowed `Stdlib.compare` (or `Pervasives.compare`) with `List.compare`, and the following no longer works.

```
sort compare [2; 3; 1]
```

There are a few solutions to this.

### Don't open `List`

Without opening `List`, you can successfully refer to the polymorphic `compare` from `Stdlib` or `Pervasives`.

```
List.sort compare [2; 3; 1]
```

We can give `List` a shorter name if it's preferable.

```
module L = List
```

Then write:

```
L.sort compare [2; 3; 1]
```

### Open `List` and explicitly refer to `Stdlib.compare`

When we open `List`, its `compare` shadows the polymorphic `compare`, but that function is still there.

```
sort Stdlib.compare [2; 3; 1]
```

That's pretty unweildly. You're probably just better off with `List.sort compare [2; 3; 1]`.

Of course, in this case you don't really need the *polymorphic* `compare`. You just need to compare integers.

```
sort Int.compare [2; 3; 1]
```

That's not so bad.

### Rename `compare`

You could bind `Stdlib.compare` to a different name. Either before or after opening `List`.

```
let cmp = compare

open List

let l = sort cmp [2; 3; 1]
```

```
open List

let cmp = Stdlib.compare

let l = sort cmp [2; 3; 1]
```

Comment: Beware that the last one is an ordinary definition that will be exposed unless hidden by a module signature, and may also shadow earlier exposed definitions externally. You can avoid that by creating and immediately opening an anonymous module (in more recent versions of OCaml)., e.g. `open struct let cmp = Stdlib.compare end`

Comment: [This discussion](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/concise-module-syntax/1344/10) may contain useful related ideas.

Comment: I find renaming the function a really useful solution. Thanks you all!